# Django - Single model inline without header

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a generic inline which I am attaching to certain models. It works fine, but the admin interface looks kind of ugly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI3UH.png

As you can see, the same heading is repeated several times. In this instance I am only ever going to add one entry to the inline, which I have setup like so:

```
class PageMetaInline(generic.GenericStackedInline):
    model = PageMeta
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1
```

Is there any way to remove the unnecessary header "Page Meta: #1" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [override the admin template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for stacked inlines for the `PageMeta` model.

Copy the original template ([view current version in trunk on the Django site)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) to 'admin/yourapp/pagemeta/stacked.html', then customise by removing the html you do not wish to display.

Comment: This won't actually work, the stacked.html template is not one of override-able templates. I ended up just adding some code into the template to check for the length of the list and hide the header if it's equal to one or less. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I've overridden `tabular.html` before, so I think `stacked.html` should be as well, unless there's a gotcha for generic inlines. I've updated my answer -- it was missing 'admin' from the path to save the overridden template to.